# What font does CMD.exe use by default for output in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, fonts

This is mostly just curiosity.

I'm not sure if it is Courier, Courier New, Lucida Console, or the like.

Comment: But the answers are the same... what now!?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Screenshot from a very fresh XP SP3 installation:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

None of them. It uses bitmap fonts. You can find then in the various `.fon` files in the Fonts folder. However, the Font Viewer won't make viewing them very nice for you. Basically each file consists of a different code page or font size.

I'd strongly advise to use a TrueType font, such as Lucida Console or Consolas, though. When set to Raster fonts the Windows console is incapable of handling Unicode.

Comment: Do you know which font is used? I see no Terminal.fon there :(

Comment: Camilo: Since when do file names coincide with font names? There are quite a few `.fon` files in the Fonts folder. Some of them are Fixedsys, some of them are System, some of them are Terminal. `85775.fon` is Terminal, for example, but there are multiple files for multiple code pages and sizes.

Comment: Weird, because I don't have a `85775.fon` file. But I understand that the filenames are different from the family names.

Comment: The basic raster font that the command prompt uses, is vgaXXXX.fon - where XXXX is the code page being used. Both the vga7XXX & vga8XXX use the same font, with only small changes in which characters are present. 

If you're looking for the "pure" DOS code page, that's somewhat aptly named as "vgaoem.fon"

Comment: Say I want to use VGAOEM.FON in my text editor. How would I go about that?? I tried opening the font and pressed install, restarted the text editor, but when I try to select font, I don't find anything new in the Terminal font! I want to use the 8x12 cp437 font like the one available in cmd but it's not listed: http://i.imgur.com/0uRZNBL.png

Answer (score 5):

If you go to properties, and click on the font tab it will tell you there.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The default font as of Windows 10 is 16 point Consolas.

Answer (score 0):

True-type 8x16 (EGA) and 9x16 (VGA) fonts:

[http://neveradudelikethisone.com/2010/01/cp437-fonts-for-windows/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160524172235/http://neveradudelikethisone.com:80/2010/01/cp437-fonts-for-windows/)

(although the 9x16 seems to have some issues with the control region)